# API not sending information

Tags: api, magento-community, soap

How can I successfully update [catalog Inventory Stock for a particular Item](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/catalogInventory/cataloginventory_stock_item.update.html)?

According to the API, this should be as simple as populating the properties and then making the call.

```
Dim objWS As MagentoService
Dim inventoryResult As Integer = objWS.catalogInventoryStockItemUpdate(
    sSessionId,
    sku,
    New catalogInventoryStockItemUpdateEntity With 
        {.manage_stock = 1, .is_in_stock = 1, .qty = 1})
```

However investigating with fiddler reveals that the message sent over the wire doesn't contain all the information, but only the quantity like below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <catalogInventoryStockItemUpdateRequestParam xmlns="urn:Magento">
            <sessionId xmlns="">62eee280a948d48b2f5c57efd4b5548f</sessionId>
            <productId xmlns="">4000</productId>
            <data xmlns="">
                <qty>1</qty>
            </data>
        </catalogInventoryStockItemUpdateRequestParam>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Am I doing something wrong, Or is this a bug with Magento? There is a [similar unanswered question on their official forums](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/290515/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fortunately, the question on the form was [answered](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/290515/#t465298). However I had a different issue. In the Magento API, you need to set the value and then tell it that you set the value.

Here's an example below:

```
Dim objWS As MagentoService
Dim inventoryResult As Integer = objWS.catalogInventoryStockItemUpdate(
    sSessionId,
    sku,
    New catalogInventoryStockItemUpdateEntity With 
        {
            .manage_stock = 1,              
            .manage_stockSpecified = True, 
            .is_in_stock = 1, 
            .is_in_StockSpecified = True, 
            .qty = 1
        })
```

Answer (score -1):

i couldnt understand how stock management working in magento, but i have found a basic solution,

```
if quantity <=0, $is_in_stock and use_config_manage_stock values will be 0;
```

otherwise magento wont update quantity to zero, stock status is: in stock!

```
$stockItemData = array(
    'qty' => $qty,
    'is_in_stock ' => $is_in_stock,
    'manage_stock ' => 1,
    'use_config_manage_stock' => $is_in_stock,
    'inventory_use_config_min_qty' =>0,
    'min_qty' =>0
);
```